# Choose the panel where to open files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Every time I open a file from the Package Explorer in Eclipse I have to drag it to the panel in the middle.

Please look this picture:

[image]

That's very annoying and affects the productivity.

How can I specify where to open the files?

Comment: Try 'Window > Reset Perspective' ('Window > Perspectives > Reset Perspective' on Eclipse Mars).

Comment: Thank you. I guess it could work but I don't want to reset the other settings on the perspective.

Comment: Yes, but I think the perspective has become confused about where to open editors so resetting the perspective may clear this.

Comment: Finally, I suppose I have to reset the perspective. Thank you @greg-449